# GeoStats report does not match with CampaignStats report in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

I am trying to build a report that shows metrics such as clicks, impressions and costs per targeted location from Google Ads.

I compare these numbers with Campaigns stats and it does not match. I got lower number from Geo stats actually. On the other hand, in google Ads application, the numbers are the same.

When I compare AdGrup stats with Campaing stats, it is matching for 100 %.

Thanks

I want to understand why there is this discrepancy and how can I solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same issue with underreported data in the GeoStats table, generated by the BigQuery Data Transfer Service. This happens when using the newer "Google Ads" API as a data source. With the old "Adwords" API as a data source this didn't happen.

The workaround I found is to integrate with the Google Ads API directly and not use the BigQuery Data Transfer Service until this issue is fixed. When importing using the Google Ads API directly there is no underreporting. For GeoStats data, [geographic_view](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v13/geographic_view) should be used.

After some more investigation, in my case, adding any `segment.geo_*` column to the Google Ads API query filters out certain rows. Because these segments are automatically included in the BigQuery Data Transfer, this seems to happen there as well. When leaving out these fields, the data matches what is reported in the Google Ads UI. My assumption is that if the geo property somehow could not be determined, it gets filtered out.

Comment: This issue seems now to be fixed by Google: the "Google Ads" source now generates a table with metrics that match the old table and the Google Ads UI.